# JAVA how to iterate over values in a map of a map

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, multimap

i have map of map i created with

`Map<String, Map<String, String>> doubleMap = new HashMap<>();`

and i try iterating over values of keys in second map.

so it can be like:

Key1 -> KeyA -> value1

|--------> KeyB -> value2

|--------> KeyC ->value3

Key2 -> KeyA -> value2

|--------> KeyB -> value4

|--------> KeyC -> value1

continuing on for long as i want.

i want to check if there is value in map that matches an other string.

so i have `mainValue = "value2"` and i try loop over all values in `doubleMap` with value variable called `thisValue` and increment counter if `thisValue.equals(mainValue)`

i dont know how i get `thisValue`. i try like this

`thisValue = doubleMap.get(currentNumKey).keySet().toArray()[counter]`

but that give me letterKeys.

if i do `thisValue = doubleMap.get(currentNumKey).get(currentLetterKey)` it give me the right value i want, but i not can iterate over all values

thanks you

Comment: I think you need to show us your code, instead of trying to explain it.  There are too many gaps (e.g. you mentioned `letterKeys` but haven't told us what this means--please don't explain what it means, just show us the code).

Comment: Post an [MCVE] demonstrating what u tried and what is the difficulty.

Comment: @ajb i show all code need. `letterKeys` clearly just = KeyA, KeyB, KeyC... it just way to understand which key i am talk about

Comment: Well, it was clear to you.  It wasn't clear to me.

Comment: If  "i show all code need"  than I hope you get help from smarter people than I am. I can't offer help based on it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> nestedMap = new HashMap<>();
nestedMap.put ...
```

Renamed (doubleMap is very misleading), and indicated that creating an empty alone map wont do.

Now you can iterate your maps like:

```
for (Entry<Map<Map<String, String>>> outer : nestedMap.entrySet) {
  outer.getKey() ... would be "Key1"
  outer.getValue() ... represents that inner map
```

And for the inner loop, it is very much the same; meaning that you can use for-each and entrySet() on the value returned by outer.getValue().

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a `Collection` of all the values in a map using the [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) method. For `doubleMap`, that will give you a collection of `Map<String,String>`. You can then iterate over that collection and for each `Map`, do the same trick to find your value:

```
for (Map<String,String> map : doubleMap.values()) {
    for (String val : map.values()) {
        if (mainValue.equals(val)) {
            // value was found
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the keys that lead to that value (which, of course, may occur more than once), then you'll need to iterate over the key set, obtained using [`Map.keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) (or entry set, obtained using [`Map.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--)) for `doubleMap` and also for each `Map` retrieved for each key. The loops should look similar.